# D2L Get enrollments

Tags: desire2learn

I'm working on a D2L add-on right now and trying to retrieve all the courses the current user is enrolled in. The only way I found so far is using the

GET /d2l/api/lp/(version)/enrollments/myenrollments/ call. This works perfectly for a small amount of courses and is extremely slow for more than approximately 50 courses. Is there any better way to retrieve all the enrollments?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For end-users, this call is indeed the one intended to address this need. Since a portion of the performance drop may come from having to process a series of data pages (requiring several calls), you can try several techniques to add a bit of performance here:

- You can pre-filter the call based on org unit type: this likely requires you  as the app developer to know the org unit type IDs for the org units of interest to your end users. For example, if your main use case here is "student wants to see all the course offerings she's enrolled in", then you can provide the appropriate org unit type ID for course offering org units to your API call. This becomes more difficult if your app must address several different back-end services, or you don't know the org unit type ID used by the back-end service for the relevant org unit types.
- You can try using an HTTP library that can pool connections, and batch together the calls that fetch all the data pages you need to get the complete list of enrollments needed. This will provide you with some benefit to overhead on each call, but the performance benefit will likely only be marginal.

Currently, this API route does not allow the caller to request a particular data page size, and allowing that would improve the overall latency involved in this use case: for example, requesting a page size of 500 records could conceivably fetch back all the enrollments in a single call. I would judge page-size requesting to be a completely reasonable feature enhancement to request, and I would encourage you to request it on D2L's [Product Idea Exchange](https://community.desire2learn.com/d2l/lp/navbars/1796/customlinks/external/15394); in fact, I'd be rather surprised if someone hasn't already done so.